# Nexus 5 nothing bootable?

Tags: adb, clockworkmod-recovery, nexus-5

I add Paranoid OTA on my Nexus 5, and I tried to uninstall it.

During the processus, everything totally failed and my phone start rebooting itself all the time.

Now :

ADB is not working. (I tried to end and restart the server but nothing to do) My phone is not recognize on my computer (windows 8.1) I can't install the driver on my computer

And i CANNOT start my phone, I don't have any more any system on it ...

I'm totally lost and I don't know what to do =/

i'm trying to install ADB to install Android 4.4.4 but impossible, my phone is connect to my computer but windows doesn't recognize it (and i uninstall and reinstall the driver with the package manager from android studio)

Someone can help me =/ ?

Comment: Can you get it into fastboot mode?

Comment: @DanHulme  
No, windows cannot recognize my Nexus 5 ... (linux same)

Comment: I'm not asking about connecting it to your PC. Can it boot into fastboot mode?

Comment: @DanHulme My phone can boot into fastboot mode yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Windows doesn't recognize the phone but I still want to try something.
Download Wugfresh toolkit from here: (For download links just scroll down, there are some mirrors)

http://www.wugfresh.com/nrt/

Once you install it, click "Full driver installation guide...". This will give you a thorough guide to uninstalling remaining drivers and installing the needed ones.

Hopefully, it will help you install the necessary drivers for the N5.
If it does work, Press the "flash stock + unroot" button on the right (I think you should check "**soft-bricked/bootloop**").

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi @Eran, thank for help, the soft is awesome ! but my still is still impossible to be connected to windows so it's imposible to use it :(

Comment: The driver installation guide gives you 4 driver options. Have you tried them all?

Comment: nop ... My phone is still not recognize on windows :(

Comment: Excellent :). What did you do eventually? I'm sure people would appreciate if you could edit your question and explain the solution.

Comment: I just used the answer of you finally.
But for windows to recognize my phone, I had to launch it in recovery mode (where you have starts, boot recovery and exit) and stay THERE ! In this place, windows recognize the phone and you can install a new rom.